# Asymmetric Numeral Systems Arithmetic

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations, projective-space, projective-schemes

Recently, I've read about the [ANS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_Numeral_Systems), where each symbol get described on a basis with size that is relative to its frequency.

I was wondering if it is possible to obtain meaningful arithmetic operations on such systems.

In particular, assuming that the symbols have an numerical meaning, then, in the r-ANS formulation:

Letting $S = (s_1,s_2,s_3,\ldots, s_n)$  be the input string of numeral symbols from the alphabet set $\mathcal{A} = \{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k \}$ of size $k$. Further, let's assume the data has the frequency counts $\mathcal{F} = \{ F_{a_1}, F_{a_2},\ldots, F_{a_k} \}$, which are integers proportional to the probability mass distribution $\{p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k\}$ of the symbols, such that $M = \sum_{i=1}^k F_i$, (and hence, $p_i = \frac{F_{a_i}}{M}$) and the cumulative frequency counts is denoted by $C_{a_i} = \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} F_{a_j}$.

Then, in this system, a symbol of $t+1$ digits is described as:

$$X_t = \left\lfloor \frac{X_{t-1}}{F_{s_t}} \right\rfloor * M + C_{s_t} + mod(X_{t-1}, F_{s_t})$$
​​
My questions are:

- is it possible to obtain the sum of two numbers in the symmetric system from a sum in the asymmetric system? (and vice-versa?)
- what is the meaning (in the symmetrical sense), if any, of the sum of two numbers in this asymmetrical system?
- is it reasonable to look for mappings of arithmetical operations between the symmetric and asymmetric numeral systems?

Any clues and ideas are much appreciated

Comment: For all F_s=1 we get standard base M numeral systems. For M and F_s all being natural powers of e.g. 2, we get ~prefix codes. Existence of other "nice" special cases looks a difficult open question, maybe some advanced algebra could allow for such "homomorphic compression" (?)

Comment: @JarekDuda I am honored to get your response on this. Indeed, making homomorphic compression based on ANS could be very significant. A direction that (I think) might work is finding an appropriate Winograd domain.  However, I didn't figured all the details yet. Would love to share thoughts in case you find it interesting

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting. I am not very fluent with abstract algebra, the general difficulty might come with chaotic behavior - small changes on one side often lead to large on the other (what makes e.g. tANS promising for simultaneous encryption). Maybe try to write a paper, e.g. starting with simple special cases.